# Extract numerical value before a string in R

Tags: r

I have been mucking around with regex strings and strsplit but can't figure out how to solve my problem.

I have a collection of html documents that will always contain the phrase `"people own these"`. I want to extract the number immediately preceding this phrase. i.e. '732,234 people own these' - I'm hoping to capture the number 732,234 (including the comma, though I don't care if it's removed). 
The number and phrase are always surrounded by a . I tried using Xpath but that seemed even harder than a regex expression. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

example string:  >742,811 people own these<

-> 742,811

Comment: Please do not use regular expressions to work with HTML. Can you _please_ post a representative sample of the _actual_ HTML or a link to the source? You should be using XML operations. It's kind of sad two folks are aiding this path fraught with peril.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `str_extract_all` from the `stringr` library:

```
str_extract_all(data, "\\d{1,3}(?:,\\d{3})*(?:\\.\\d+)?(?= people own these)")
```

Comment: It works nearly perfectly, returns a large list of empty characters and the value i'm after. Is there any reason it seems to return a bunch of listed NA's as well?

Comment: @Permafrost: How could anyone know the answer to that question, given the lack of any example?

Comment: @Permafrost I'm not in front of an R console at the moment, but I would suggest starting with a smaller test text, and see if you can do some debugging.

Comment: Thanks very much, I was just after a quick fix so I used 'str_extract' to return a character vector not a list, then used x[!is.na(x)] (where x is the character vector) to remove the NA's and get the final value. I'll keep reading up on Xpath, but this is a fast way to get what I need.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following.

```
val <- "742,811 people own these"
gsub(' [a-zA-Z]+',"",val)
```

Output will be as follows.

```
[1] "742,811"
```

***Explanation:*** using gsub(global substitution) function of R here. Putting condition here where it should replace all occurrences of space with small or capital alphabets with NULL for variable `val`.